# I encountered the following error when trying to run BT-Unet: a TensorFlow program on pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-image

2023-05-06 17:30:37.471901: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1680] Unknown: AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'swapaxes'
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 247, in **call**
return func(device, token, args)

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 135, in **call**
ret = self._func(*args)

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 645, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "F:/yuanye-pph/BT-Unet/BT-Unet_test.py", line 609, in iou_metric_batch
value = value + iou_metric(y_true_in[batch], y_pred_in[batch])

File "F:/yuanye-pph/BT-Unet/BT-Unet_test.py", line 551, in iou_metric
labels = label(y_true_in > 0.5)

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure_label.py", line 93, in label
return clabel(input, neighbors, background, return_num, connectivity)

File "skimage\measure_ccomp.pyx", line 348, in skimage.measure._ccomp.label_cython

File "skimage\measure_ccomp.pyx", line 322, in skimage.measure._ccomp.reshape_array

File "skimage\measure_ccomp.pyx", line 299, in skimage.measure._ccomp._apply_swaps

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 401, in **getattr**
self.**getattribute**(name)

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'swapaxes'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/yuanye-pph/BT-Unet/BT-Unet_test.py", line 787, in 
callbacks=callbacks)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1184, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 885, in **call**
result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 950, in _call
return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3040, in **call**
filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1964, in _call_flat
ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 596, in call
ctx=ctx)
File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'swapaxes'
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 247, in **call**
return func(device, token, args)

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 135, in **call**
ret = self._func(*args)

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 645, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "F:/yuanye-pph/BT-Unet/BT-Unet_test.py", line 609, in iou_metric_batch
value = value + iou_metric(y_true_in[batch], y_pred_in[batch])

File "F:/yuanye-pph/BT-Unet/BT-Unet_test.py", line 551, in iou_metric
labels = label(y_true_in > 0.5)

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure_label.py", line 93, in label
return clabel(input, neighbors, background, return_num, connectivity)

File "skimage\measure_ccomp.pyx", line 348, in skimage.measure._ccomp.label_cython

File "skimage\measure_ccomp.pyx", line 322, in skimage.measure._ccomp.reshape_array

File "skimage\measure_ccomp.pyx", line 299, in skimage.measure._ccomp._apply_swaps

File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\YYtf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 401, in **getattr**
self.**getattribute**(name)

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'swapaxes'

```
 [[node EagerPyFunc_1 (defined at F:/yuanye-pph/BT-Unet/BT-Unet_test.py:614) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_45017]
```

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node EagerPyFunc_1:
IteratorGetNext (defined at F:/yuanye-pph/BT-Unet/BT-Unet_test.py:787)
EagerPyFunc (defined at F:/yuanye-pph/BT-Unet/BT-Unet_test.py:654)

Function call stack:
train_function

versions:
tensorflow 2.6.0
scikit_image 0.17.2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.